# Get values of current row that is being updated in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView *GridView1* and I want to

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    // Get value from row of GridView and update in query below... 
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE tblDonors SET DName = 'Dummy' WHERE DName = 'Test'";
}
```

How to get values of current row so that I can update that row in the Database.

I have tried this but does not work

```
GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GridView1.EditIndex instead of e.RowIndex.

```
TextBox Tb = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("TextBox1");
if(tb!=null){
 string s = tb.Text;
}
```

Or Try this:

```
  TextBox Tb = (TextBox) GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].Cells[0].Controls[0];
    if(tb!=null){
     string s = tb.Text;
    }
```

Also take a look at [e.NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes because you are getting Controls[0] i.e. first control. If you want the text you need to try as in the update.

Comment: TextBox1? where is this or where to define this

Comment: From what field are you trying to get the value? Is your GV generating columns automatically?